# Start for ts object in R for 15 minute data

Tags: r, time-series

I have a timeseries dataset with me which of 15 min resolution. I want to make a `ts` object from it. The data is being stored as a `data.frame`. I did it like that.

```
my.ts <- ts(df$X, freq=365*24*60/15, start=c(2019, 01)) / 1000.
```

I don't know how to provide that `start` argument for `ts` as my data is starting on time `2019-01-04 19:45:00`.

How can I provide this info for `ts`.?

Using `ts` as shown below don't give me any error.

```
my.ts <- ts(df$X, freq=365*24*60/15, start=c(2019, 01, 04, 19, 45)) / 1000.
```

But I am not sure whether this is the correct method to it.

This is a sample of the data.

```
x <- 'Timestamp,X
    2019-01-04 19:45:00,-11.9
    2019-01-04 20:00:00,-16.88
    2019-01-04 20:15:00,-15.48
    2019-01-04 20:30:00,-19.85
    2019-01-04 20:45:00,-19.85
    2019-01-04 21:00:00,-13.65
    2019-01-04 21:15:00,-19.71
    2019-01-04 21:30:00,-15.47
    2019-01-04 21:45:00,-11.73
    2019-01-04 22:00:00,-18.68
    2019-01-04 22:15:00,-9.51
    2019-01-04 22:30:00,-19.25
    2019-01-04 22:45:00,-19.51
    2019-01-04 23:00:00,-19.64
    2019-01-04 23:15:00,-19.7
    2019-01-04 23:30:00,-19.53
    2019-01-04 23:45:00,-17.67
    2019-01-05 00:00:00,-19.22
    2019-01-05 00:15:00,-19.11
    2019-01-05 00:30:00,-19.15
    2019-01-05 00:45:00,-19.22
    2019-01-05 01:00:00,-15.48
    2019-01-05 01:15:00,-11.46
    2019-01-05 01:30:00,-19.55
    2019-01-05 01:45:00,-19.43
    2019-01-05 02:00:00,-18.66
    2019-01-05 02:15:00,-18.46
    2019-01-05 02:30:00,-15.54
    2019-01-05 02:45:00,-17.41'
```

I read it a dataframe like this

```
df <- read.csv(text=x)
```

Comment: I have updated the question to show a sample of dataframe

Comment: Your code is working fine for me. Are your data in the right format? Please could you replace the provided data with the output of `dput(df)`? It's the appropriate way to provide data, and we get the information about how your data is stored.

Comment: The code works fine, I was not sure whether that is the correct way to provide start time for a ts object when the data is 15 minutes.